# How to aggregate other columns when ST_ClusterIntersecting function is used

Tags: postgis, postgresql

As stated in the [PostGIS documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterIntersecting.html)

> ST_ClusterIntersecting is an aggregate function that returns an array
>   of GeometryCollections, where each GeometryCollection represents an
>   interconnected set of geometries.

Is it possible to aggregate other columns along with this geometry aggregation?
Particularly I would like to get arrays of IDs corresponding to the geometries in each aggregated geometry collection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest to use [`ST_ClusterDBSCAN`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html) instead;
as a window function it can be applied in the scope of a simple `SELECT`, where it assigns cluster ids based on the given parameter:

```
SELECT *,
       ST_ClusterDBSCAN(<geom>, 0, 1) OVER() AS _clst
FROM   <your_table>;
```

Setting the `eps` distance to 0 effectively clusters by intersection. This will return your initial table, with the `_clst` column representing the respective cluster.

From here, you can aggregate based on the `_clst` column:

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(<id>) AS id_agg,
       ST_Collect(<geom>) AS geom
FROM   (
  SELECT *,
         ST_ClusterDBSCAN(<geom>, 0, 1) OVER() AS _clst
  FROM   <your_table>
) q
GROUP BY
  _clst
;
```

---

This should be considerably more performant than any construct needed to get the same results with the aggregate functions.

And, with `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` being a window function, it allows to `PARTITION BY` given colums, effectively allowing you to cluster over rows with a specific (set of) attribute(s).